# Visual c++ and SAX

Tags: c++, xml, sax

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276505 
This site has a download for a Win32 application wizard. I am currently developing a win32 application and this XML parser would come in very handy.
I have searched the internet for documentation on using SAX with MS Visual Studio. Does anybody have any experience with this? I am just looking for some documentation or any information about using SAX with VS c++.

Comment: This should be able to run on any Windows machine, XP and up.

Comment: well i was going to say that windows vista sp2 and 7 have their own xml parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come to a resolution. I used xerces, which has SAX and SAX2 built in. Linking a library and referencing a *.dll is necessary:

http://xerces.apache.org/